# Nutch - why are my url exclusions not excluding those urls?

Tags: regex, apache, solr, nutch

Surprise! I have another Apache Nutch v1.5 question. So in crawling and indexing our site to Solr via Nutch, we need to be able to exclude any content that falls under a certain path.

So say we have our site: `http://oursite.com/` and we have a path that we don't want to index at `http://oursite.com/private/`

I have `http://oursite.com/` in the `seed.txt` file and `+^http://www.oursite.com/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*` in the `regex-urlfilter.txt` file

I thought that putting: `-.*/private/.*` also in the `regex-urlfilter.txt` file would exclude that path and anything under it, but the crawler is still fetching and indexing content under the `/private/` path.

Is there some kind of restart I need to do on the server, like Solr? Or is my regex not actually the right way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the url is accepted by first regex and the second one isn't checked anymore. If you want to deny URLs, put their regexes first in list.